# Pandas/Geopandas: Showing Latitude/Longitude Points from two different dataframes on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, geopandas

I've been following this tutorial:https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-101-plot-any-data-with-a-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-map-98e01944b972 and have successfully plotted one map but am having trouble adding a second layer of points to the same plot. 
I think it's a general misunderstanding of how plots work.

The following works:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
nycmap.plot(ax=ax)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( df['LONGITUDE'], df['LATITUDE'])]
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}, geometry = geometry)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
nycmap.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color="blue")
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, markersize=1, color = "yellow", marker = 'o', label = "permit")
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})
```

[Good Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5cBY.png)

Now I have a second dataframe that I'd like to plot on top of the first but I'm not quite sure how to make it work. Depending on the range of values, they'll have different colors.

Here's what I've tried interwoven with the above code:

```
geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( df2['Longitude'], df2010['Latitude'])]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
geo_df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}, geometry = geometry2)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
nycmap.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color="blue")
geo_df2[geo_df2['sum'] <= 1236].plot(ax=ax, markersize=1, color = 'red', marker = 'x', label = "Below")
geo_df2[(geo_df2['sum'] > 1237) & (geo_df2['sum'] <= 1606)].plot(ax=ax, markersize=1, color = 'orange', marker = 'x', label = "Average")
geo_df2[(geo_df2['sum'] < 1607) & (geo_df2['sum'] <= 2087)].plot(ax=ax, markersize=1, color = 'green', marker = 'x', label = "Max")
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})
```

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong? It doesn't show the good plot, only a fraction of an empty plot

Comment: I don't see something obviously wrong in the code. You will probably have to provide a reproducible example. Also, do you get the good plot if you just plot the full `geo_df2` like you did in the first example (without taking the subsets)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I actually don't get a good plot. Which leads me to believe there may be something wrong with the data in the dataframes. But I can't imagine what it'd be. They both have the geometry column with the Points, as well as latitude and longitude. But when I try to plot it on it's own, there's no background map of the city, just a small blank cut off window.

Comment: Try adding the `.loc` operator? `geo_df2.loc[geo_df2['su...`